# Set action to custom module admin Button

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I created a custom module, with a button in System > Configuration. **Clicking on this button should call a function and then inform the user about the function's results** (I suppose by reloading the same page and showing some messages.)

Could you please give me some instructions about how to do that?

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <CustomModules translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>CustomModules</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </CustomModules>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <CustomModules translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>Fix Products</label>
            <tab>CustomModules</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

            <groups>
                    <fields>
                        <re_enable_configurables translate="label">
                            <label>Click this button to manually fix products.</label>
                            <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                            <frontend_model>mymodule/adminhtml_system_config_button</frontend_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </re_enable_configurables> 
                    </fields>
                </CustomModules_group>
            </groups>
        </CustomModules>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Button.php**

```
<?php 
class CustomModules_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Button extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{

    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("some_kind_of_url_idk");

        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setClass('scalable')
                    ->setLabel('FIX products!')
                    ->setOnClick("setLocation('$url')")
                    ->toHtml();

        return $html;
        $buttonHtml = $this->_getAddRowButtonHtml($this->__('FIX products!'));
        return $buttonHtml;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: you have missing node for group in system.xml for `<CustomModules_group>`